# jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i need to use the animate property for a less than usual activity. i am new at jquery so i dont know if this thing works right out of the box for jquery but lets see.

```
    $('#Zoom').toggle(function() {
            img.removeAttribute("height");
        $("#draggable").draggable();                
        },
```

the above function zooms into an image by removing the height constraint and displays the image its entire resolution. can i somehow make this transition animate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $("#zoom").animate({'height':'1024px'},{'queue':false,'duration':2000}
```

But you need to know the height of picture at full resolution to pass to call to animate. you may try passing 100% like this:

```
  $("#zoom").animate({'height':'100%'},{'queue':false,'duration':2000}
```

More about jquery animation can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods).

Answer (score 2):

Yes just simple do:

```
$('#zoom').animate({'height' : '100%'},600)
```

That will work.

Answer (score 1):

as TheVillageIdiot says, but little bit different syntax:

```
$("your_image_selector").animate({"height": "100%"}, 400);
```

hope it helps.